# Calculating ratio in R

Tags: r

If I have this data set:
    `Name <- c("Bill", "Ben", "Lisa", "Maya")
     Xnum <- c(5, NA, 10, NA)
     Ynum <- c(10, 5, NA, NA)
     MyData <- data.frame(Name, Xnum, Ynum)`

This gives me a data set of:

```
 `print(MyData)
  Name Xnum Ynum
1 Bill    5   10
2  Ben   NA    5
3 Lisa   10   NA
4 Maya   NA   NA`
```

Dividing X by Y will give me a ratio which I want. This is easy to do
    `MyData$Ratio <- MyData$Xnum / MyData$Ynum`

the problem is the values with NA's in them. In those cases I have the following requirement

```
`If Xnum == NA AND Ynum == NA
    Ratio = 1
Else if Xnum == NA AND Ynum >= 0
    Ratio = 1
Else if Xnum >= 0 AND Ynum == NA
    Ratio = 0
Else
    Ratio = Xnum / Ynum`
```

I tried it as a function passing in Xnum and Ynum and returning ratio but it is not doing what I expect it to. The function is:

```
`determine_ratios <- function( PrevTotal, AllTotal ) {

    if ( (is.na(PrevTotal)) && (is.na(AllTotal)) ) {
        return(as.double(1.0))
    } else if ((PrevTotal  >= 0) && (is.na(AllTotal)) ) {
        return(as.double(1.0))
    } else if ((is.na(PrevTotal)) && (AllTotal >= 0) ) {
        return(as.double(0.0))
    } else {
        return(as.double(PrevTotal / AllTotal ))
    }
}`
```

And I have called it as this:

```
`MyData$Ratios <- determine_ratios(MyData$Xnum, MyData$Ynum)`
```

The output I get is this:

```
`print(MyData)
  Name Xnum Ynum Ratios
1 Bill    5   10    0.5
2  Ben   NA    5     NA
3 Lisa   10   NA     NA
4 Maya   NA   NA     NA`
```

The expected output would be:

```
`print(MyData)
  Name Xnum Ynum Ratios
1 Bill    5   10    0.5
2  Ben   NA    5     1
3 Lisa   10   NA     0
4 Maya   NA   NA     1`
```

Thanks

Comment: Add your desired output.

Comment: One thing, you don't need `as.double` or the .0 in 0.0. For example, `identical(0, as.double(0.0))` returns TRUE. It looks like you are coming from a different language. In base R there are doubles and integers, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

MyData$Ratios <-
case_when(
    is.na(MyData$Xnum) & is.na(MyData$Ynum) ~ 1,
    is.na(MyData$Xnum) & MyData$Ynum >= 0 ~ 1,
    MyData$Xnum >= 0 & is.na(MyData$Ynum) ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ MyData$Xnum / MyData$Ynum
)
```

Comment: Tim that is perfect, exactly what I wanted. case_when that is not one that I have come across in the manuals yet.